# NameError in Python Script

Tags: python

I am working through an example Python script from the book "Doing Math with Python" and I keep running up against a NameError which tells me my variable isn't defined, when, it looks to me like it is defined.

I'm using Python 3.4 and the code is

```
 '''
    Gravitational Calculations
    '''

    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

    #Draw the graph

    def draw_graph(x,y):
        plt.plot(x,y,marker='o')
        plt.xlabel('Distance (m)')
        plt.ylabel('Force (N)')
        plt.title("Gravitational force as a function of distance")

    def generate_F_r():
        #Generate values for r
        r=range(100,1001,50)

        #Empty list to store F values
        F=[]

    #G Constant
    G=6.674*(10**-11)
    #Two masses
    m1=0.5
    m2=1.5

    #Calculate F and append it into the F-list
    for dist in r:
        force=G*m1*m2/(dist**2)
        F.append(force)

    #Call the Draw Plot Function
    draw_graph(r,F)

    if __name__=='__main__':
        generate_F_r()
```

The error it gives me is:
NameError name 'r' is not defined

Isn't it defined in the line that states r=range(100,1001,50)?

Why isn't it taking this as a definition?

I'm sure there is something glaringly simple and incredibly stupid I'm doing but I am at my wits end as to how such a simple thing could be so hard.

Thanks!

Comment: What code should be in `def generate_F_r():`. Because as is, the error is valid. `r` only exists within the `generate_F_r` method. And from how your code is currently structured, you are trying to use it outside the method.

Comment: In addition, either your indentation is wrong, or r is used before generate_F_r() is called

Answer (score 0):

Code in functions is not executed until the function is called.  You don't call `generate_Fr()` until after you have already tried to reference `r`.  Even if you *did* call the function first, though, `r` is still just a local variable.  You need to make it global with `global r` at the beginning of the function.